# What is our policy on the question-asker reviewing edits on their own question?

Tags: discussion

After submitting an [edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31387) a few days ago, I had it approved twice - by other unrelated users and declined once - by the user whose question was being edited.  Im my opinion the question-asker should skip over a review of an edit on their own question to prevent bias.  I agree that the edit was on the edge of being a minor edit but I through it added value to the question an apparently two other users agreed with me.

Comment: +1 for asking, it's a good topic and I think it needs exposure.

Answer (score 10):

Across the whole SE network the OP has the last word. If the OP rejected the edit, no matter how many other users approved it, the edit remains rejected, and is not seen in a good way to try and suggest it again.

If you think the edit is absolutely needed, you can try to speak with the OP in the comments or in chat.

Comment: I'd just add that the OP has the last word because it is their question, and they are the only one that can **truly** know the intent and how the edit might change that.  I'd be happier if every OP actually reviewed edits on their posts!

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Federico, that the author has the final say. If you have strong feelings about an edit that you consider should not have been rolled back, it won't harm to flag it for the moderators' attention with a full description of the issue (if you do not want to discuss it in comments/chat).

With that said, if I had reviewed [that edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31387), I would have **rejected** it with the reason *that it doesn't make the post easier to read* (I can't find the exact verbatim given to the reviewers at the moment).

I see a cosmetic change (not a correction) to the title in order to change **one word** in the body (that's the way I see it, maybe it's different from what you intended).

The [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/editing) says:

> Edits are expected to be **substantial** and to leave the post better than you found it.

---

As a reviewer, the first thing I look at is the edit remark, in that case it was:

> switched a few words around and edited title.

But why? As any active user would have noticed, I'm one of the [prolific editors](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) (not counting own posts) on the main site, but before I reached 2,000 rep, I made only [one edit suggestion](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/14897/ymb1?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), because in most cases any typo/minor issue can be neglected without adding it to the review queue.

Comment: Well, editing your own post doesn't add it to the review queue though, so that argument doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @Lnafziger - The badge I linked to is for "editing 500 posts **excluding own**".

Comment: I was actually referring only to your last paragraph, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Lnafziger - I'm not following sorry. The last paragraph (the whole post really) is about editing someone else's post -- If it's something obvious that I'm missing, please edit my post.

Comment: The last paragraph seems to suggest that you should ignore minor typos so that it isn't added to the review queue.  In the case of someone editing their own post though, it never goes in the review queue.

Comment: @Lnafziger - Yes. If a user is under 2000 rep., it's better per the help center to not add to the queue very minor edits such as correcting 1 typo. If it's their own post, well, that's not what this post is about.

Comment: Actually, that's the entire premise of the question, which is why I brought it up.  ;-)  ***"What is our policy on the question-asker reviewing edits on their own question?"***

Comment: @Lnafziger - I see where the confusion is coming from now. But note that the asker here is not the author of the post in question, but someone who submitted an edit suggestion. So I was also addressing the edit suggestions in general.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to bring it to your attention so that you can clarify if you want to.  Thanks!